# Formulário de contato mensagem "Enviado com sucesso"

Tags: php, formulário

Alguém pode me responder por favor o porque destes erros no formulário?

[image: Tirei o print e coloquei o código abaixo para melhor entendimento.]

```
<?php
// Display errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

extract($_POST);

// Configuracoes sobre a pagina
$bgcolor      = "#FFFFFF";
$titulo       = ">> Meu site";
$assunto      = "Meu site";
$remetente    = "$email";
$destinatario = "email@gmail.com";

// Corpo da página
echo "<head><title>$titulo</title><meta http-equiv=refresh content=100;URL=http://www.meusite.com.br/cont-consulta.htm;target=parent></head>\n";
echo "<p align=center> $nome! Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso! <br> Retornaremos dentro de 24hs. Obrigado! <p>" ;
echo "      </font></b></font>";

// Dados e configurações da função mail()
$headers  = "From: $assunto<$remetente>" . "\r\n";
$mensagem = ":: meu site ::\n
\nNome: $nome
\nEmail: $email
\nCidade: $cidade
\nEstado: $estado
\nMensagem: $msg\n";

// Envia o email
$enviaemail = mail("$destinatario", "$assunto", "$mensagem", $headers);

// Rodapé da página
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português :D Recomendo visitar o [tour] para conhecer um pouco mais como o Stack Overflow funciona. Seja mais específico em sua pergunta, coloque o erro em texto e não em imagem, pois isso irá facilitar a visualização por quem vê pelo celular.

Comment: Os valores para as variáveis `$nome, $cidade, $estado, $msg` estão sendo enviados? Coloca seu HTML na pergunta

Comment: Toda vez que é feita uma operação com uma variável de `"valor indefinido"` o PHP exibe a mensagem Notice: Undefined variable.

Comment: As variáveis `$nome`, `$email`, `$cidade`, `$estado` e `$msg` estão setadas em algum lugar?

Answer (score -1):

Não tenho certeza se você pode usar múltiplas linhas em uma string com aspas duplas `"`. Tenta mudar para aspas simples `'` ou apenas deixá-la em uma linha, já que está usando o `\n`.

```
$mensagem = ':: meu site ::\n
\nNome: $nome
\nEmail: $email
\nCidade: $cidade
\nEstado: $estado
\nMensagem: $msg\n';
```

ou

```
$mensagem = ":: meu site ::\n\nNome: $nome\nEmail: $email\nCidade: $cidade\nEstado: $estado\nMensagem: $msg\n";
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php